# Excluding some characters from a Regular Expression range

Tags: .net, regex, unicode

I have a regex that selects words in a unicode range

```
[\u0D80-\u0DFF]*
```

I want to exclude words that include a certain character for example \u0D92.

How should I change the expression?

Comment: Which regular expression engine / language are you working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net supports another notation for [Character Class Subtraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction):

```
[\u0D80-\u0DFF-[\u0D92]]*
```

Example (using the .Net engine): [http://regexstorm.net/tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Cu0D80-%5Cu0DFF-%5B%5Cu0D92%5D%5D%2a&i=%E0%B6%92%E0%B6%93%E0%B6%93)

Answer (score 2):

Just build two ranges; that is, make gaps in your range for the values you wish to exclude...

```
[\u0D80-\u0D91\u0D93-\u0DFF]*
```

Comment: what if the number of these characters are more than one? is there a way to exclude them cleanly?

Comment: Doesn't scale very elegantly if he has several "invalid" characters.

Comment: @nima: I would assume this regex would/could be built by a program or script and what the result looks like isn't all that important as long as comments are with it.

Comment: At last I wrote a program to generate the expression. I guess there's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You could can *subtract* characters from a character class by doing

```
[\u0D80-\u0DFF&&[^\u0D92]]*
```

`[a-z&&[^egi]]` matches all characters from `a` to `z` except `e`, `g` and `i`.

Comment: Nothing against your answer but what regex engine supports the `&&` syntax?

Comment: The [Java regex engine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). I don't know if it's a standard notation though.

Answer (score 0):

Use lookaheads to implement set intersection:

```
(?x)(?:
     (?!\x{d92})
     [\x{d80}-\x{dff}]
)
```

That creates an atom that fits your criteria.  Qualify at will.

I don't trust your `\uXXXX` notation. It is always a bad sign when you see something that uses it, because it is some ancient Unicode 1 legacy notation that assumes Plane 0 only. That means it hasn't been useful since Unicode 2, way back deep into the previous millennium. I would avoid it if at all possible, because you don't want into get into bad habits that don't work for 16/17th of the Unicode namespace.

I have therefore used the standard `\x{...}` notation used in Java 7, ICU, and Perl, which is not bigotted against Planes 1-16 of Unicode. Indeed, in the languages acursed with a UTF-16 representation (yes, Java, I'm looking at you), that is the only possible way to do non-BMP ranges.

Comment: Thanks for info on hex notation. but I couldn't get this to work in .Net

Comment: @nima: Well of course you can't get it to work if you  aren't using your own dialect's version of hex escapes. The point is that `\uXXXX` is inherently flawed. Duh. You had no language tag, so you should not expect anything that works for you.